# How to prove onto function with concept of 'sets'

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

A function $f: A\rightarrow B $ is said to be onto if $f(A)=$Range$(f)=B=$ co-domain. $
f(A) $ is subset of $B $
$B$ is subset of $f(A)$
Two sets are equal when both are the subset of eachother. $A$ is subset of $B$ and $x$ belongs to A implies that $x$ belongs to $B$.

How to show the function $f$ is  onto iff $B$ is subset of Range$(f)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Range $f$ is always a subset of codomain, here B. With this fact, $f$is onto iff every point in the codomain B is an image of an element in the domain A under $f$ iff  range $f$ = B iff B is a subset of range $f.$

Answer (score 0):

Here I use, in particular, the following basic facts :

(1) set A is equal to set B iff A is a subset of B , *and reciprocally*.

(2) set A is a proper subset of B iff A is included in B but B is not included in A ( i. e. all the elements of A are also in B, but at least one element of B does not belong to A).

(3) set A is included in B iff A is a proper subset of B or A equals B.

---

As to $\Rightarrow$

(1) Suppose $f$ is onto

(2) It means that *ran*$(f)=B$, or, equivalently, $B = $*ran*$(f)$.

(3) So , by definition of set equality,  $B\subseteq ran(f)$

As to $\Leftarrow$

(1) Suppose that $B$ is a subset of *ran* $(f)$, in symbols: 
 $B \subseteq$*ran*$(f)$.

(2) It means ( by definition of inclusion)  that either $B  \subset $ *ran*$(f)$ OR $B = $ *ran*$(f)$.

(3) But $B \subset $ *ran*$(f)$ is impossible. If $B$ were a proper subset of *ran*$(f)$ it  would mean that some element of *ran*$(f)$ does not belong to $B$, i.e., it would mean that for some $a$ in $A$, $f(a)$ is not in $B$. In that case, $f$ would not be a function from $A$ to $B$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

(4) Hence the second disjunct - in (2) - must be true, that is : $B  = $ *ran*$(f)$.